# javascript function call to fetch data and display to screen on page load

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I am trying to call the javascript function to fetch the data from DB.  when the page loads the
other product should fetch the data on click event. But only onclick I is fetching the data and when the page loads first time it is blank page.
Please guide me. please find below is my code. java and jsp page

```
<% for(int i=0;i<vProductLine.size();i++){
   if(i == 0) { %>              
<%--                    <td id="onglet<%= i %>" class="<% if(nOnglet.equals(""+i)) out.print("ongletActif"); else out.print("ongletInactif"); %>" onload="displayOnglet('<%= i %>')">  --%>
<td id="onglet<%= i %>" class="<% if(nOnglet.equals(""+i)) out.print("ongletActif"); else out.print("ongletInactif"); %>" onload="displayOnglet('<%= i %>')">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr><td nowrap align="center"><b><j2ee:text id="xmlFile" tag="<%= vProductLine.elementAt(i).toString() %>"/></b></td></tr>
                            <tr><td align="center"><span id="obj_<%= vProductLine.elementAt(i) %>"></span></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
<% }else{ %>
                    <td id="onglet<%= i %>" class="<% if(nOnglet.equals(""+i)) out.print("ongletActif"); else out.print("ongletInactif"); %>" onclick="displayOnglet('<%= i %>')">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr><td nowrap align="center"><b><j2ee:text id="xmlFile" tag="<%= vProductLine.elementAt(i).toString() %>"/></b></td></tr>
                            <tr><td align="center"><span id="obj_<%= vProductLine.elementAt(i) %>"></span></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
<% }} %>
```

Comment: You mean `onload="displayOnglet('<%= i %>')"` is not working?

Comment: yes, after adding onload function, still for first product list is not loading the data. it is showing blank screen. but when we click to the other product list on the same page and going back(by click) to the first product. it is loading the data.

Comment: Actually `onload` event never fires on `td` tag, the tags that you can define onload for them are : `<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> and <style>`.

Comment: ok, I have to call onload function on first index element in this case what should I use. because body tag is already used for another onload function in my page.

Comment: What do you mean by _because body tag is already used for another onload function in my page._? you can define multiple actions in body onload, for example: 
`function f1(){ // do something};
function f2(){ // do something};
document.body.onload= function(){ f1(); f2();  }`

this approach won't solve for your problem?

Comment: <BODY onload="init(<%=nOnglet%>,<%=vProductLine.size()%>)" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
<center>
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>//  how to call another js function on body tag with onload event.
  <td height="1"></td> 
  <td rowspan="2" align="center" valign="top">
   <jsp:include page="../general/header.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="fileName" value="<%= jspParameter.getXmlFileName() %>" />
   </jsp:include>
   <br>
  </td>

Comment: How to call another javascript function from body tag.

Comment: `<body onload="f1();f2();f3()">` all three functions will call when body has loaded. In your case you can do it by `<body onload="init(<%=nOnglet%>,<%=vProductLine.size()%>); anotherFunc()"`

Comment: Can we call displayOnglet(0); inside the init() function.               init(n,nOnglets){
 currentOnglet = n;
 if(document.form0 != "[object]")
  return;
 var savePL = source.selectSingleNode("root/select").getAttribute("pl");
 var pl = savePL;
 
 for(var i=0;i<nOnglets;i++){
  var pl = eval("document.form"+i).PL.value;
  setOngletTotalObj(pl);

  source.selectSingleNode("root/select").setAttribute("pl",pl);
  getReadyStateStyle(pl);
 }
 source.selectSingleNode("root/select").setAttribute("pl",savePL);
 
 // calling diplayOnglet function for default menu
 displayOnglet(0);
}

Comment: Actually I can't read your code correctly, but you can call your function inside init function. it seems ok.

Comment: <BODY onload="init(<%=nOnglet%>,<%=vProductLine.size()%>); displayOnglet(0)" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">

Comment: I have tried this way but it didn't work.

Comment: What was the problem? `displayOnglet` never called?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the answer?

Comment: calling displayOnglet method from <script> tag I have not tried. There is an error while opening in the first page . It shows in inspect element. "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference" page and line number commun.js(23,3).This may the problem of loading the data on on page load.  This is the code of error page on 23 line . function setOngletTotalObj(pl){

 obj = getObjectif(pl);
 //mto delete from total
 if (pl="GC"){
  mto = document.all.item("MTO").innerHTML;
  alert(mto+ "  " + obj)
 }

Comment: your error actually is related to `mto = document.all.item("MTO").innerHTML;` whe you run your function do have and html item in the page with name `MTO` ?

Comment: <MTO>M.T.O. (comb.)</MTO> it is defined in a XML file.

Comment: I am not sure from where the MTO file is reading.  If  we do the below changes will it work ? 
 if (pl="GC"){
  if( document.all.item("MTO") != undefined ) {
   mto = document.all.item("MTO").innerHTML;
   alert(mto+ "  " + obj)
  }   
 }

Comment: you should use `if(document.all.item("MTO") != null)` It just prevents the error, but I don't know you can achieve your goal or not.

Comment: Here is my code and it solved the problem . if(document.all.item("MTO") != null) &&(document.all.item("MTO") != undefined)    . Thank you very much for support.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution in the comment doesn't help to solve your problem, another solution is to put a script tag and call your function inside the script, like this:

```
<% for(int i=0;i<vProductLine.size();i++){
if(i == 0) { %>              
<td id="onglet<%= i %>" ...>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr><td nowrap align="center">...</td></tr>
     <tr><td align="center">...</td></tr>
   </table>
 </td>
<script>
   displayOnglet('<%= i %>'); //or wathever you want to do on td's onlaod
</script>
<% }... %>
```